# Mongoose: Model updates are not persisted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add an additional property containing an Array to each document stored in my MongoDB collection.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var artistSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    city: String,
    imageFile: String,
    tracks:Array <-- This is the new property I'd like to add to each doc
});

// define an Artist model with this mongoose instance
mongoose.model('Artist', artistSchema);

// create a new connection
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/treefort');

//@param artist - Document to update
//@param tracks - Array to add to the document
    function updateArtistWithTracks(artist, tracks, callback){

        var conditions = { name: artist.name }
            , update =  {tracks : tracks}
            , options = { multi: true };

        Artist.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
    }
```

'updateArtistWithTracks' is called for each document found using Artist.findOne() ie

```
function findArtistByName(artistName, callback){
    Artist.findOne({name: artistName}, function (err, art) {
        if(err) throw 'Could Not Find Arist With Name: ' + artistName;
        callback(art);
    });
};
```

The callback invoked from the update function does not contain any error and the number of affect document is alway 1 :

```
Artist.update(conditions, update, options, callback); //callback is called with (null, 1) each time.
```

When I query my mongodb all of the documents remain unchanged. Can anyone help?

**Update**

'tracks' is an array of objects. This is what it looks like:

```
 "Tracks": [
        {
            "title": "Dance of jesters part 1 Oct. 10",
            "duration": "98466",
            "stream_url": "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/25087329/stream"
        },
        {
            "title": "Little french suite mov.3 Oct. 10",
            "duration": "96401",
            "stream_url": "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/25087293/stream"
        }]
```

Is it because I am attemping to add a subdocument that my update fails?

**Update Again**

Here is my code in it's entirety. I've simplified the code a bit. Still the new "tracks" property containing an array of objects will not be added to the document!?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/treefort');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var dbConnectionOpen = false;

var artistSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    city: String,
    imageFile: String,
    tracks: [
        {
            "title": String,
            "duration": String,
            "stream_url": String
        }
    ]
});

var Artist = mongoose.model('Artist', artistSchema);

/** Mongo Connection Callbacks**/
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    dbConnectionOpen = true;
    start();
});

var trackData;
function start() {
//Read Track JSON File
    var fs = require('fs');
    var file = '/Users/nick/DropBox/artist-tracks.json';
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw 'Could Not read source file';
        trackData = JSON.parse(data);
        runUpdate();
    });
}

function runUpdate() {
    var currentArtist = trackData.shift();
    if (currentArtist) {
        Artist.findOne({ name: currentArtist.Name }, function (err, artDoc) {
            if (err) throw 'Could Not Find Artist With Name: ' + currentArtist.Name;
            if (artDoc) {
                Artist.update(
                    { _id: artDoc._id},
                    {$push: {"tracks": {title: currentArtist.Tracks[0].title, duration: currentArtist.Tracks[0].duration, stream_url:currentArtist.Tracks[0].stream_url }}},
                    { upsert: true },
                    function (err, numberAffected, raw) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);

                    });
            }
            if (trackData) {
                console.log(trackData.length)
                runUpdate();
            }
            if(trackData.length === 0){
                process.exit(0);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: So where exactly is `tracks` coming from? Not seeing where that input parameter is.

Comment: tracks is an array of objects. See me my update

Comment: Sure, but what I meant was we cannot see where this is ever being passed into your `updateArtistWithTracks` function. Even if something is being passed through to `findArtistByName` the parameter is missing from the callback that is being passed through.

Comment: I've updated the post to include all of my code.